# problem with JavaScript sortable html table

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

[Here](http://www.webtoolkit.info/sortable-html-table.html) is webtoolkit but ...

```
var t = new SortableTable(document.getElementById('myTable'), 100);
```

2 parameters

```
function SortableTable (tableEl) {
```

and where is height ?

Here is my try to make it work but it doesn't works (only commented code works but for ff and ie only)

```
    function ScrollableTable(tableEl, tableHeight, tableWidth) 
{
    this.tbody = tableEl.getElementsByTagName('tbody');
    this.thead = tableEl.getElementsByTagName('thead');
    this.tfoot = tableEl.getElementsByTagName('tfoot');

    this.getInnerText = function(el) {
        if (typeof (el.textContent) != 'undefined') return el.textContent;
        if (typeof (el.innerText) != 'undefined') return el.innerText;
        if (typeof (el.innerHTML) == 'string') return el.innerHTML.replace(/<[^<>]+>/g, '');
    }

    this.getParent = function(el, pTagName) {
        if (el == null) return null;
        else if (el.nodeType == 1 && el.tagName.toLowerCase() == pTagName.toLowerCase())
            return el;
        else
            return this.getParent(el.parentNode, pTagName);
    }

    this.sort = function(cell) {

        var column = cell.cellIndex;
        var itm = this.getInnerText(this.tbody[0].rows[1].cells[column]);
        var sortfn = this.sortCaseInsensitive;

        if (itm.match(/\d\d[-]+\d\d[-]+\d\d\d\d/)) sortfn = this.sortDate; // date format mm-dd-yyyy
        if (itm.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "").match(/^[\d\.]+$/)) sortfn = this.sortNumeric;

        this.sortColumnIndex = column;

        var newRows = new Array();
        for (j = 0; j < this.tbody[0].rows.length; j++) {
            newRows[j] = this.tbody[0].rows[j];
        }

        newRows.sort(sortfn);

        if (cell.getAttribute("sortdir") == 'down') {
            newRows.reverse();
            cell.setAttribute('sortdir', 'up');
        } else {
            cell.setAttribute('sortdir', 'down');
        }

        for (i = 0; i < newRows.length; i++) {
            this.tbody[0].appendChild(newRows[i]);
        }

    }

    this.sortCaseInsensitive = function(a, b) {
        aa = thisObject.getInnerText(a.cells[thisObject.sortColumnIndex]).toLowerCase();
        bb = thisObject.getInnerText(b.cells[thisObject.sortColumnIndex]).toLowerCase();
        if (aa == bb) return 0;
        if (aa < bb) return -1;
        return 1;
    }

    this.sortDate = function(a, b) {
        aa = thisObject.getInnerText(a.cells[thisObject.sortColumnIndex]);
        bb = thisObject.getInnerText(b.cells[thisObject.sortColumnIndex]);
        date1 = aa.substr(6, 4) + aa.substr(3, 2) + aa.substr(0, 2);
        date2 = bb.substr(6, 4) + bb.substr(3, 2) + bb.substr(0, 2);
        if (date1 == date2) return 0;
        if (date1 < date2) return -1;
        return 1;
    }

    this.sortNumeric = function(a, b) {
        aa = parseFloat(thisObject.getInnerText(a.cells[thisObject.sortColumnIndex]));
        if (isNaN(aa)) aa = 0;
        bb = parseFloat(thisObject.getInnerText(b.cells[thisObject.sortColumnIndex]));
        if (isNaN(bb)) bb = 0;
        return aa - bb;
    }

    // define variables
    var thisObject = this;
    var sortSection = this.thead;

    // constructor actions
    if (!(this.tbody && this.tbody[0].rows && this.tbody[0].rows.length > 0)) return;

    if (sortSection && sortSection[0].rows && sortSection[0].rows.length > 0) {
        var sortRow = sortSection[0].rows[0];
    } else {
        return;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < sortRow.cells.length; i++) {
        sortRow.cells[i].sTable = this;
        sortRow.cells[i].onclick = function() {
            this.sTable.sort(this);
            return false;
        }
    }

/*
    this.initIEengine = function() {

        this.containerEl.style.overflowY = 'auto';
        if (this.tableEl.parentElement.clientHeight - this.tableEl.offsetHeight < 0) {
            this.tableEl.style.width = this.newWidth - this.scrollWidth + 'px';
        } else {
            this.containerEl.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
            this.tableEl.style.width = this.newWidth + 'px';
        }

        if (this.thead) {
            var trs = this.thead.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            for (x = 0; x < trs.length; x++) {
                trs[x].style.position = 'relative';
                trs[x].style.setExpression("top", "this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.scrollTop + 'px'");
            }
        }

        if (this.tfoot) {
            var trs = this.tfoot.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            for (x = 0; x < trs.length; x++) {
                trs[x].style.position = 'relative';
                trs[x].style.setExpression("bottom", "(this.parentElement.parentElement.offsetHeight - this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.clientHeight - this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.scrollTop) + 'px'");
            }
        }

        eval("window.attachEvent('onresize', function () { document.getElementById('" + this.tableEl.id + "').style.visibility = 'hidden'; document.getElementById('" + this.tableEl.id + "').style.visibility = 'visible'; } )");
    };


    this.initFFengine = function() {
        this.containerEl.style.overflow = 'hidden';
        this.tableEl.style.width = this.newWidth + 'px';

        var headHeight = (this.thead) ? this.thead.clientHeight : 0;
        var footHeight = (this.tfoot) ? this.tfoot.clientHeight : 0;
        var bodyHeight = this.tbody.clientHeight;
        var trs = this.tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr');
        if (bodyHeight >= (this.newHeight - (headHeight + footHeight))) {
            this.tbody.style.overflow = '-moz-scrollbars-vertical';
            for (x = 0; x < trs.length; x++) {
                var tds = trs[x].getElementsByTagName('td');
                tds[tds.length - 1].style.paddingRight += this.scrollWidth + 'px';
            }
        } else {
            this.tbody.style.overflow = '-moz-scrollbars-none';
        }

        var cellSpacing = (this.tableEl.offsetHeight - (this.tbody.clientHeight + headHeight + footHeight)) / 4;
        this.tbody.style.height = (this.newHeight - (headHeight + cellSpacing * 2) - (footHeight + cellSpacing * 2)) + 'px';

    };

    if (!this.tbody) return;

    if (document.all && document.getElementById && !window.opera) this.initIEengine();
    if (!document.all && document.getElementById && !window.opera) this.initFFengine();
    */


    this.tableEl = tableEl;
    this.scrollWidth = 16;

    this.originalHeight = this.tableEl.clientHeight;
    this.originalWidth = this.tableEl.clientWidth;

    this.newHeight = parseInt(tableHeight);
    this.newWidth = tableWidth ? parseInt(tableWidth) : this.originalWidth;

    this.tableEl.style.height = 'auto';
    this.tableEl.removeAttribute('height');

    this.containerEl = this.tableEl.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement('div'), this.tableEl);
    this.containerEl.appendChild(this.tableEl);
    this.containerEl.style.height = this.newHeight + 'px';
    this.containerEl.style.width = this.newWidth + 'px';

    var thead = this.tableEl.getElementsByTagName('thead');
    this.thead = (thead[0]) ? thead[0] : null;

    var tfoot = this.tableEl.getElementsByTagName('tfoot');
    this.tfoot = (tfoot[0]) ? tfoot[0] : null;

    var tbody = this.tableEl.getElementsByTagName('tbody');
    this.tbody = (tbody[0]) ? tbody[0] : null;
}
```

**The trouble is I got no THead and TBody here :**

```
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" style="width:990px; border-style: outset; border-width: 4px; " runat="server" ScrollBars="Horizontal">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="100%" 
        ondatabound="GridView2_DataBound" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="both" ShowFooter="True" onrowdatabound="GridView2_RowDataBound" 
        HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
            VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
            VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" 
            HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" 
            HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
```

Is there some wais to make this script works for GridView ?..

and Ive got a trouble with hiding of vertical scrollbar if there is horizontal scroll bar (but that's trouble if I use commented code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just have a new function that instantiates a new SortableTable? Or do you have to rewrite everything for some reason?

Something like:

```
function ScrollableTable(tableEl, tableHeight, tableWidth) 
{
var table = new SortableTable(document.getElementById('myTable'), 100);
do stuff to the table that you whant..like width and height..
}
```